# Execute method in Apex batch never called

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have an apex class though which I do batch processing of some xml files. Below is a part of the code from my apex class:

```
global class DoHMHParsing implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{ 
    private static Integer inBatch = 0;
    public Boolean testMode = true;
    public static List<string> parsingerrors = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> parsedmsg = new List<string>();
    global list<string> processedmsg = new List<string>();
    global list<string> processederrors = new List<string>();
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        system.debug('inside start');
        inBatch++;
        String sql = 'Select id,Channel__c,Queue__c,Converted_Object_ID__c from NBAT_DEEP_Message__c where Converted_Object_ID__c = null AND Queue__c LIKE \'DS.NBAT.DEEP.DOHMH.LIC.RECVQ\'';
        sql += this.Testmode ? ' LIMIT 5' : 'LIMIT 2000';
        system.debug('after start');
        return Database.getQueryLocator(sql);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<NBAT_DEEP_Message__c> scope) {
        inBatch++;
        system.debug('inside execute');
        try {
            parseHealthMessages(scope);
            processedmsg.addAll(parsedmsg);
            processederrors.addAll(parsingerrors);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }

        inBatch--;
    }
```

The Xml which I am parsing is stored at a custom object location called NBAT_DEEP_Message__c.  Channel__c,Queue__c,Converted_Object_ID__c are custom fields in NBAT_DEEP_Message__c object. I enter 'DEEP.NBAT.SVRCONN' in channel_c field and 'DS.NBAT.DEEP.DOHMH.LIC.RECVQ' in Queue_c field. I attach an xml file in notes&attachment section. I am parsing this xml and creating record in  my Salesforce org. This works fine in Production but when I do this in testing environment there is no record created. Also in test, only the start() method is invoked and execute() method is not invoked, which means there is no batch processing happening. What can be a problem here? How can I go about debugging this. I have attached debug logs for more information:

```
26.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
14:11:26.016 (16248107)|EXECUTION_STARTED
14:11:26.016 (16273968)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pU0000000lzD8|DoHMHParsing
14:11:26.019 (19640715)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
14:11:26.019 (19707197)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
14:11:26.019 (19728348)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
14:11:26.019 (19749008)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
14:11:26.019 (19768452)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
14:11:26.019 (19804926)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
14:11:26.019 (19998518)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
14:11:26.020 (20027221)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
14:11:26.020 (20039060)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
14:11:26.020 (20087263)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[10]|DoHMHParsing.contEmailID|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20094537)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[7]|DoHMHParsing.contFaxNumber|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20098289)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[9]|DoHMHParsing.contMobTelNumber|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20101851)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[8]|DoHMHParsing.contTelNumber|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20105265)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[3]|DoHMHParsing.identificationId|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20108820)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[2]|DoHMHParsing.inBatch|Integer|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20113800)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[14]|DoHMHParsing.parsedmsg|List<String>|true|true
14:11:26.020 (20117979)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[13]|DoHMHParsing.parsingerrors|List<String>|true|true
14:11:26.020 (20121560)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[11]|DoHMHParsing.pername|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20125546)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[5]|DoHMHParsing.regeffDate|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20129176)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[6]|DoHMHParsing.regexpDate|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20132519)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|DoHMHParsing.statusDate|String|false|true
14:11:26.020 (20264927)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:29
14:11:26.029 (29109094)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:71
14:11:26.029 (29121973)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:24
14:11:26.029 (29127359)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:22
14:11:26.029 (29155259)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01pU0000000lzD8|DoHMHParsing.DoHMHParsing()
14:11:26.029 (29166952)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
14:11:26.029 (29176398)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
14:11:26.029 (29182242)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
14:11:26.029 (29197811)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:4
14:11:26.029 (29227494)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|DoHMHParsing.inBatch|0
14:11:26.029 (29237561)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
14:11:26.029 (29261333)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[3]|DoHMHParsing.identificationId|""
14:11:26.029 (29271143)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[4]
14:11:26.029 (29286776)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[4]|DoHMHParsing.statusDate|""
14:11:26.029 (29291341)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[5]
14:11:26.029 (29299380)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[5]|DoHMHParsing.regeffDate|""
14:11:26.029 (29302928)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[6]
14:11:26.029 (29310052)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[6]|DoHMHParsing.regexpDate|""
14:11:26.029 (29313375)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[7]
14:11:26.029 (29320090)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[7]|DoHMHParsing.contFaxNumber|""
14:11:26.029 (29323596)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
14:11:26.029 (29330366)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|DoHMHParsing.contTelNumber|""
14:11:26.029 (29333555)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[9]
14:11:26.029 (29340314)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[9]|DoHMHParsing.contMobTelNumber|""
14:11:26.029 (29343644)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[10]
14:11:26.029 (29350526)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[10]|DoHMHParsing.contEmailID|""
14:11:26.029 (29353947)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[11]
14:11:26.029 (29361287)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[11]|DoHMHParsing.pername|""
14:11:26.029 (29364897)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[13]
14:11:26.029 (29371609)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:4
14:11:26.029 (29451053)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
14:11:26.029 (29478462)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[13]|DoHMHParsing.parsingerrors|{"s":1,"v":[]}|0x5b40fc09
14:11:26.029 (29484081)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
14:11:26.029 (29489739)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[14]|Bytes:4
14:11:26.029 (29523984)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
14:11:26.029 (29539165)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[14]|DoHMHParsing.parsedmsg|{"s":1,"v":[]}|0x4aac7cbf
14:11:26.029 (29550082)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|DoHMHParsing
14:11:26.029 (29557295)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
14:11:26.029 (29561777)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
14:11:26.029 (29572492)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[17]|this|DoHMHParsing|true|false
14:11:26.029 (29628286)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[17]|this|{"processederrors":"0x7e934579","processedmsg":"0x22ef5e16","testMode":true}|0xb8f8770
14:11:26.029 (29645110)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[17]|BC|Database.BatchableContext|true|false
14:11:26.029 (29781498)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[17]|BC|{"jobId":"707550000058OaTAAU"}|0x5ba2d79a
14:11:26.029 (29798495)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[17]
14:11:26.029 (29801586)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[18]
14:11:26.029 (29806322)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[18]|Bytes:12
14:11:26.029 (29858532)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|inside start
14:11:26.029 (29871230)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[19]
14:11:26.029 (29884161)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[19]|Bytes:4
14:11:26.029 (29896951)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[19]|DoHMHParsing.inBatch|1
14:11:26.029 (29901313)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[20]
14:11:26.029 (29906394)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[20]|Bytes:163
14:11:26.029 (29911757)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[20]|sql|String|false|false
14:11:26.029 (29925215)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[20]|sql|"Select id,Channel__c (143 more) ..."
14:11:26.029 (29929067)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[21]
14:11:26.029 (29940446)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[21]|Bytes:8
14:11:26.029 (29968174)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[21]|Bytes:171
14:11:26.029 (29980806)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[21]|sql|"Select id,Channel__c (151 more) ..."
14:11:26.029 (29984780)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[22]
14:11:26.029 (29989161)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[22]|Bytes:11
14:11:26.030 (30012895)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|after start
14:11:26.030 (30023157)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[23]
14:11:26.030 (30612654)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[23]|Aggregations:0|Select id,Channel__c,Queue__c,Converted_Object_ID__c from NBAT_DEEP_Message__c 
14:11:26.051 (51748004)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[23]|Rows:1
14:11:26.051 (51796361)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[23]|Bytes:20
14:11:26.071 (71930053)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
14:11:26.071 (71930053)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 200
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 60000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 12000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 0
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 0
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 1
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

14:11:26.071 (71930053)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

14:11:26.071 (71963923)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|DoHMHParsing
14:11:26.073 (73021169)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: A few questions: (1) When you say "testing environment" - do you mean in a testmethod or running the job from the sandbox via the apex scheduler or anonymous apex?  (2) Note that there are multiple debug logs created when a batch job is run - the start() method will be in one debug log and the execute()'s will be in separate debug logs. Are you looking in the right place?

Comment: Hi thanks. By test I meant running this batch in Sandbox via anonymous. And I do not know where to find logs for start(),execute() and finish(). The log which I pasted was from what I see in Execute Anonymous. This logs open up first when I run the batch apex class. How to locate other log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tips to help you debug your batch class

Since you are running it in Execute Anonymous from your Sandbox (presumably Developer Console), the debug log you presented is only your constructor+`start ()` method. You can see that the QueryLocator returns one row

Each execute() invocation (you will have only one as your test environment only has one record) creates its own log that you will find in the Logs panel on the Developer Console.

*Aside - I have found that from time-to-time, these logs don't appear and that closing/restarting the Developer Console does the trick.*

Personally, I am not enamored of the default logging that SFDC uses:

```
APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

and prefer much coarser debugging (SYSTEM : Error, APEX_CODE: INFO where all my debug statements use `LoggingLevel.INFO`) but you can do as you will.

A few other tips for your batch class:

1. `global` access modifier is not required unless you are doing a managed package - use `public` instead
2. The `Boolean testMode` should be derived from a custom setting and not hardcoded in the class - or, alternatively, derive the `limit x` from a custom setting.
3. You should think about whether to allow for partial successes and document accordingly.
4. Writing to a custom `Log__c` object in `finish()`is a great way to record errors for later analysis - especially if you support partial successes. Your catch block isn't going to very useful as the debug logs for the batch job may not be available when you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I am wondering why the row returned by Querylocator is not added to the Salesforce database? What does a QueryLocator has in it? Does it get records from the database table? How is it different from SOQL query?

Comment: A QueryLocator is used by batch APEX to provide a way to 'find' all records in the SOQL WHERE clause and pass the results in batches (batch size default = 200) to the `execute()` method.  A normal SOQL query can fetch only 50,000 rows but with a queryLocator used in batch APEX, there is really no limit at all as each execute() resets the Limits - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm .